# ios signal SIGABRT - [<UIViewController 0x681be50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, compilation, sigabrt

i m developing an app, in which includes the lite and full version of this app.
I split this to with

```
#ifdef FULL #endif
```

and

```
#ifdef LITE #endif
```

The past view Days i was developing the full app and didnt check the lite version.

Now, when i m trying to run the lite version, i get this error:

```
2012-03-28 19:17:45.867 Unknown class CustomerViewController in Interface Builder file.
2012-03-28 19:17:45.867 iScale optometry lite[4779:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x681be50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key    settingsButton.'
```

I know, this could be caused by IB Links which are messed up because of the #ifdef splitting.
But i changed much in the past view days and i dont know where to search the error - is there a way to get a better errormessage, to see, where the problem lies.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you actually have a class called CustomerViewController?  If so, is it being built into the LITE version?

Comment: yes, i have this class - i currently dont build it, because its a screen which is only visible in the Full version - but i ll try to build it too

Comment: ok, that helped - i included the CustomerViewController in the LITE build and only give it the basic implementation for the LITE verison... thanks a lot!